# Which encoding works best for Windows API calls?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I use a function from the Windows API called [GetFileAttributesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) to retrieve attributes from a file. The function signature is defined as:

```cpp
DWORD GetFileAttributesW([in] LPCWSTR lpFileName);
```

`LPCWSTR`  is defined as `const wchar_t*`.

I want to call the function:

```cpp
fs::path inputPath = ...
GetFileAttributesW(inputPath.whichMethodHere()?);
```

The given input path is of type [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) that has several convenience converters like:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path::string()
std::filesystem::path::wstring()
std::filesystem::path::u8string()
std::filesystem::path::u16string()
std::filesystem::path::u32string()
```

The two functions `wstring()` and `u16string()` stand out here for me. Both are defined with a character type of `wchar_t` and `char16_t` respectively.

## Question 1:

What is the main difference between `wstring()` and `u16string()`. Does `wstring()` return something different than `u16string` in real life scenarios?

## Question 2:

Which encoding does the Windows API generally expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: `char16_t` doesn't provide any substantial advantage over `wchar_t` on Windows, and it's less convenient to use. Choose `wchar_t`, always. Microsoft's implementation of [`path::native()`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/filesystem#L961-L964) returns a `std::wstring` (not a `std::u16string`) as a matter of a conscious decision.

---

> Which encoding does the Windows API generally expect?

Windows uses UTF-16LE encoding internally, everywhere, but doesn't enforce well-formedness anywhere. Particularly when dealing with filesystem objects, any sequence of 16-bit values ([with a few exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)) is admissible.

> What is the main difference between `wstring()` and `u16string()`. Does `wstring()` return something different than `u16string` in real life scenarios?

The answer is more involved than [this proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73248690/1889329)  suggests. `wstring()` and `u16string()` return a `std::wstring` and `std::u16string`, respectively, which are `std::basic_string` instantiations for `wchar_t` and `char16_t`.

The question thus boils down to this: What is the difference between `wchar_t` and `char16_t`? The answer is disturbingly unspecific. The section on [character types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) lists them as following:

> - `wchar_t` - type for wide character representation (see [wide strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide)). Required to be large enough to represent any supported character code point. It has the same size, signedness, and alignment as one of the integer types, but is a distinct type.
> - `char16_t` - type for UTF-16 character representation, required to be large enough to represent any UTF-16 code unit (16 bits). It has the same size, signedness, and alignment as [`std::uint_least16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), but is a distinct type.

If you read carefully, neither type has a fixed size, and neither type is required to use any particular character encoding. It is specifically true that C++ makes no guarantees that `char16_t` **must** store UTF-16 encoded text (only that the type must be able to).

What does this mean in practice? Since Windows uses UTF-16LE everywhere, `wchar_t` has historically always been a 16-bit type on Windows. The introduction of `char16_t` on Windows hasn't changed much: It's just another type capable of representing UTF-16 encoded text. Since it is a distinct type, you're going to have to cast when passing a `char16_t*` into a function (which has always accepted a `wchar_t*`, or, rather, one of its C approximations).

On Windows, you can pretty much assume that `wchar_t` and `char16_t` will be the same width, and hold UTF-16 encoded characters. You can thus also assume, that `wstring()` and `u16string()` will return the same binary data. `wchar_t` is generally more useful as that's the native type used in interfaces, and doesn't require casts.

Comment: Holy smokes, thanks so much for the detailed answer!!

Comment: Great answer! +1 for the well researched answer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `std::wstring` and `std::u16string` is that `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t` and `std::u16string` uses `char16_t`, which you managed to figure out by yourself.

`wchar_t` is not required to use UTF-16 encoding. Linux uses UTF-32 for `wchar_t` for example. `wchar_t` is only required to be able to store 'wide' strings, whatever that means, while `char16_t` is required to be able to store UTF-16 encoded text everywhere.

As the parameter is `LPCWSTR` the expected type of that parameter is `const wchar_t*`, which you also managed to figure out by yourself.

Windows functions which ends in `A` expects `char` pointers, and windows functions which ends in `W` expects `wchar_t` pointers. There are also macros which does not end in either, and these macros expand to either the `A` version or the `W` version depending on whether unicode is enabled during compilation.

Note: There is also `std::filesystem::path::native()` if you want the string as the native string type.

My recommendation would be `GetFileAttributesW(inputPath.c_str());` as `c_str` returns a 'native' pointer.

Comment: Ah, I never knew that `wchar_t` had different sizes. So on Windows `wstring()` and `u16string()` technically return the same thing, but it wouldn't be portable. Is that correct?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Correct, but `GetFileAttributesW` isn't portable anyway. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Makes sense, but I fully get that now. Thanks so much! Accepted answer.

Comment: It should be noted that anything in Windows where you're dealing with file names or paths. you _must_ use wide strings. UTF-8 does not operate correctly.

Comment: *"`char16_t` is required to use UTF-16 everywhere"* - That would be way too good of an idea for C++ to adopt it. The truth is, this statement is wrong, and C++ missed another chance to actually consider Unicode as a thing. The [actual guarantuees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#char16_t) are far less useful (neither is its size fixed, nor is any given character encoding required).

Comment: @paddy "*UTF-8 does not operate correctly*" - it does if you [opt in to enable UTF-8 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page), then you can use UTF-8 in most `A`nsi-based APIs (particularly file system APIs), and they will internally convert to UTF-16 as expected.

Comment: Sorry, have to down-vote for being factually incorrect. It reads like it was written by someone who is under the impression that the good intentions for `char16_t` actually made it past ISO standardization (they didn't).

Comment: @IInspectable I see. I didn't read up on this too much while writing it. I have edited the factually problematic part to be less misleading.